# Ruby `printf` mix named references and `*` flag

Tags: ruby, formatting

#### Motivation

Say we have a number of randomly sized numbers, generated with something like:

```rb
values = (0...10).map { |_| rand(1_000_000) }
```

We can determine the width required to display each of these numbers comfortably with the following:

```rb
width = values
        .map { |x| Math.log10(x).to_i + 1 } 
        .max
```

and use this width in [`Kernel#printf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.5/Kernel.html#method-i-printf) like so:

```rb
values.each { |x| printf("%*d\n", width, x) }
```

taking advantage of the `*` flag to:

> Use the next argument as the field width.

as per [`Kernel#format`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.5/Kernel.html#method-i-format).

#### Issue

If we wanted to make use of both named references and the `*` flag inside the format string, we then start to run into issues. Attempting the following:

```rb
printf("%<value>*d\n", width, value: x)
```

raises the following error:

```
main.rb:7:in `printf': one hash required (ArgumentError)
```

and flipping the order of the arguments to:

```rb
printf("%<value>*d\n", value: x, width)
```

raises the following error:

```
main.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
...%<value>*d\n", value: x, width) }
```

As a test, omitting `width` entirely (with no expectation of success):

```rb
printf("%<value>*d\n", value: x)
```

gives the following error:

```
main.rb:7:in `printf': unnumbered(1) mixed with named (ArgumentError)
```

Is it categorically currently not possible to use named references with the `*` flag in Ruby string formatting?

Comment: Tip: Using `printf` is kind of unusual in contemporary Ruby. Instead: `"..." % [ width, x ]` where [`String#%`](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/string#method-i-25) does the job.

Comment: You can cheat this with `"%<value>#{width}"` but at that point maybe zero padding the string is a better option.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. Fair point about the use of `String#%`; while it may be anachronistic, my personal preference is to wrap up `puts` + `%` into the one call to `printf`. Either way, I am getting broadly the same errors when using `%` (as would be expected) ✌️

Comment: I'm not sure you can mix unnumbered and named styles in a single format template. `*` has always been given second-rate consideration.